# Catching SIGINT and SIGTSTP signals causes bug

Tags: c, signals

I am making a simple shell. When the user clicks <kbd>control-Z</kbd> I want to simply toggle the state of foreground only mode. When the user clicks <kbd>control-C</kbd>, I want to terminate only foreground processes (background child processes should ignore it).

If I run my shell and send in commands like "ls" or "sleep 10" they work. After doing so If I press either <kbd>control-C</kbd> or <kbd>control-Z</kbd>, this also works. It is only after sending in <kbd>control-C</kbd> or <kbd>control-Z</kbd> that the normal commands stop working. For example, sending "ls" after <kbd>control-C</kbd> won't execute. Why is this? Is the signal messing with STDIN?

**Update to comments received**

Now using `sigaction` I can handle <kbd>control-C</kbd> signals correctly. Trying <kbd>control-Z</kbd>, however, causes a fork bomb. How can I prevent this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int last_exit_status = 0;
int last_termination = 0;
int backgroundChildrenRunning = 0;
int backgroundPid = 0;
int ignoreBackground = 0;


void child_sigint_handler(int signum) {
    //nothing here for now
}
void child_sigint_handlerSec(int signum) {
    //do nothing here for background process
}

void sigint_handler(int signum) {// Signal handler for SIGINT (Ctrl-C)
   //nothing here now
}

void sigtstp_handler(int signum) {// Signal handler for SIGTSTP
  //nothing here for now
}

void check_background() {
    if (backgroundChildrenRunning > 0) {        //this function is to print the background process termination signal
        int currentStatus;
        int completedChild = waitpid(-1, &currentStatus, WNOHANG);      //use WHOHANG so it does not block

        if (completedChild > 0) {
            if (WIFEXITED(currentStatus)) {
                printf("Background process with ID %d has been completed. Exit value: %d.\n", completedChild, WEXITSTATUS(currentStatus));
                last_termination = WEXITSTATUS(currentStatus);
            }
            else {
                if (completedChild == backgroundPid) {
                    printf("Background process with ID %d has been completed. Terminated by signal: %d.\n", completedChild, WTERMSIG(currentStatus));
                    last_termination = WTERMSIG(currentStatus);
                }
            }
            backgroundPid = 0;
            backgroundChildrenRunning -= 1;
        }
    }
}

char* prompt(int pid);

//main func
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    char *token;
    char *argv[1024]; // Array to store command and arguments
    int i = 0;

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    sa.sa_handler = sigint_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);

    struct sigaction sa_tstp;
    sa_tstp.sa_handler = sigtstp_handler;
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &sa_tstp, NULL);

    while(x == 0) {
        check_background();
        int pid = getpid();
        char* command = prompt(pid);   //get user input
        if (command != NULL) {

            int childExitMethod;
            pid_t spwanPID = fork();

            token = strtok(command, " "); // Split the command into tokens
            while (token != NULL) {//add in all tokens into arr
                argv[i] = token;
                token = strtok(NULL, " ");
                i++;
            }
            argv[i] = NULL;
            int hasSymbolEnd = 0;
            if (strcmp(argv[i - 1], "&") == 0){     //checks to see if background or foreground process
                if (ignoreBackground == 0) {
                    hasSymbolEnd = 1;
                }
                argv[i - 1] = NULL; // Remove the '&' symbol
            }

            switch (spwanPID){
            case -1:
                last_exit_status = 1;
            case 0:
                if (hasSymbolEnd == 1) {
                    backgroundPid = getpid();
                    sa.sa_handler = child_sigint_handlerSec;
                } else {
                    sa.sa_handler = child_sigint_handler;
                }

                execvp(argv[0], argv);
                last_exit_status = 1;
                exit(1);
                
            default:
                if (hasSymbolEnd == 0){
                    waitpid(spwanPID, &childExitMethod, 0); // Wait for the child only if background
                    if (WIFEXITED(childExitMethod) && !WEXITSTATUS(childExitMethod)) {
                        last_exit_status = 0;
                    } else if (!WIFSIGNALED(childExitMethod)){
                        printf("bash: %s: command not found\n", command);
                        last_exit_status = 1;
                    }

                    if (WIFSIGNALED(childExitMethod)) { //Check if the child was terminated by a signal
                        int terminatedBySignal = WTERMSIG(childExitMethod);
                        printf("Terminated by signal %d\n", terminatedBySignal);
                    }
                } else {
                    printf("background pid is %d\n", spwanPID); 
                    backgroundChildrenRunning += 1;
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char* prompt(int pid) {
    printf("%d:", pid);
    fflush(stdout);

    char* input = NULL;
    size_t input_size = 0;
    ssize_t read_bytes = getline(&input, &input_size, stdin);// Use getline to read user input

    if (read_bytes == -1) {
        free(input); // Free the memory
        return NULL;
    }

    if (input[read_bytes - 1] == '\n') {// Remove the newline character at the end
        input[read_bytes - 1] = '\0';
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Note: Calling `printf`, `exit` from a signal handler is not safe. See: [`signal-safety(7)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)

Comment: @Oka I can use write instead of printf, what about exit? how can I exit a child from a signal handler?

Comment: [`_exit`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/_exit.2.html) (`_Exit`) is *async-signal-safe*. Note also, `fflush` is also unsafe.

Comment: @Oka I've changed printf to write, and exit to _exit. I also removed fflush and placed it in my main file before the prompt. The bug still persists. I added an example output. Would you know the reason behind this?

Comment: Don't use `signal()` to setup signal handlers, use `sigaction()` (and note `SA_RESTART` flag). The only type allowed to access from signal handlers is `sig_atomic_t`. On x86 it's `int` but excplicit type would be more readable. Variables accessed from signal handlers should be `volatile`. Print relevant error message after `execvp()` failure. Splitting command into tokens executes twice, in both parent and child process. Some other defects... For interactive application such as a shell i'd suggest not to mess with signal handlers but use event loop with `signalfd()`.

Comment: @dimich thanks for the help. Can you show an example of how to use signalfd() please.

Comment: @ahmed There is an example in [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html).

Comment: @dimich I used ur suggestions, now control C works perfectly. But when I try control Z I get a fork bomb. I tried to debug and couldnt figure out why. I have updated my code.

Comment: @ahmed Your code ignores the possibility that `getline()` could return `0`.  That makes `if (input[read_bytes - 1] == '\n') ...` dangerous as it will access memory outside the `input` buffer.  See [**Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input)

Comment: @AndrewHenle thanks for the heads up, I fixed it. That wasnt the issue however with the fork bomb when I try control z

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Under what circumstances can POSIX [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
 legitimately return 0?  AFAICT, it can return `-1` or a strictly positive value and never zero.  The 'return value' section of the POSIX specification is in the next comment — it barely fits into one comment.  (One possibility not obviously covered by the POSIX specification is if the file stream is connected to a non-blocking file descript; it isn't clear what should be returned if there's no data ready, but that might be the same as EOF.) _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continued…] _Upon successful completion, the getline() and getdelim() functions shall return the number of bytes written into the buffer, including the delimiter character if one was encountered before EOF, but excluding the terminating NUL character. If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if no characters were read and the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream shall be set and the function shall return -1. If an error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set, and the function shall return -1 and set errno to indicate the error._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding `SIGINT` [handling](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Signal-Handling.html), you could:

- in the main shell, ignore `SIGINT`.
- in child processes, handle `SIGINT` to terminate only if they are foreground processes.

And for `SIGTSTP` handling, implement a toggle for the foreground-only mode in the `sigtstp_handler`.

```c
// rest of your includes and global variables

void sigint_handler(int signum) {
    // Main shell should ignore SIGINT
}

void sigtstp_handler(int signum) {
    ignoreBackground = !ignoreBackground; // Toggle the state
}

// rest of your functions

int main() {
    // rest of your main function

    struct sigaction sa_ignore;
    sa_ignore.sa_handler = SIG_IGN; // Ignore signal
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa_ignore, NULL);

    struct sigaction sa_tstp;
    sa_tstp.sa_handler = sigtstp_handler; // Handle SIGTSTP
    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &sa_tstp, NULL);

    // rest of your main function

    switch (spwanPID) {
    // rest of your switch case

    case 0:
        // Child process
        if (hasSymbolEnd == 1) {
            // Background process should ignore SIGINT
            sigaction(SIGINT, &sa_ignore, NULL);
        } else {
            // Foreground process should handle SIGINT
            struct sigaction sa_child;
            sa_child.sa_handler = SIG_DFL; // Default signal handling
            sigaction(SIGINT, &sa_child, NULL);
        }

        execvp(argv0, argv);
        // rest of your case 0
    }
    // rest of your main function
}
```

You would get, for your [fork process](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-system-call/):

```
  User Input
      |
      v
   Shell Loop
      |
      +---> Fork Process
      |        |
      |        +---> Execute Command (ls, sleep)
      |        |         |
      |        |         +---> SIGINT Handling (Child)
      |        |
      |        +---> SIGINT Ignored (Background Child)
      |
      +---> SIGINT Ignored (Main Shell)
      |
      +---> SIGTSTP Toggles Foreground Mode (Main Shell)
```

---

> I still get a fork bomb every time I click control Z. However control C is handled correctly

When `SIGTSTP` is caught, it should toggle the foreground-only mode. However, it should not create new processes or interfere with the existing process management.

Make sure the main loop does not fork new processes when it is not supposed to, especially after handling `SIGTSTP`.
The `sigtstp_handler` should only toggle a flag (`ignoreBackground`). It should not perform any process creation or other complex operations.
After handling `SIGTSTP`, verify that the main loop does not fork new processes. That might be happening if the state of your program is not correctly managed after catching the signal.

I have added some `printf` for debugging:

```c
void sigtstp_handler(int signum) {
    ignoreBackground = !ignoreBackground; // Toggle the state
    printf("Toggled foreground-only mode to %d\n", ignoreBackground);
    fflush(stdout);
}

int main() {
    // rest of your main function setup

    while (x == 0) {
        check_background();
        // rest of your command reading and parsing

        if (command != NULL) {
            // tokenizing and processing the command

            if (strcmp(argv[0], "") != 0) { // Check if the command is not empty
                pid_t spwanPID = fork();

                // rest of your fork and exec logic

            } else {
                free(command); // Free the command string if it is empty
            }
        }
    }
    // rest of your main function
}
```

The main idea is to make sure empty commands or improperly parsed commands do not lead to unintended forking.

Comment: Thanks, I still get a fork bomb every time I click control Z. However control C is handled correctly.

Comment: @ahmed OK, I have edited the answer to address your comment.